# Source looses reference after angular.copy

Tags: angularjs, copy

I have a list of items. To edit one I just pass it trough a function.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in itemList" ng-click="edit(item)">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Inside the function I make a copy of the item so the user can edit without affecting it directly. I want to update the item only after a successful form response.

```
itemCopy = angular.copy(item);
// pass itemCopy to a form, edit, submit and get response
if (response.success) {
    item = itemCopy; // Update item with new data
    // angular.extend(item, itemCopy); <--- THE RIGHT WAY TO UPDATE
}
```

But when I replace 'item' content it doesn't update the item in view. Looks like 'item' looses connection to view. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new object reference which will break other references

Use `angular.extend(item, itemCopy);` which will merge the properties/values of the second into the first

Reference: [angular.extend() docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)